# Как в IDEA посмотреть все методы класса

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Смотрю видео урок, и там преподаватель в IDEA нажимает на какое-то сочетание клавиш и появляются все методы интерфейса. Прикладываю скрин с пометками. Извините за качество. Как такую вызвать, google не помог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меню `View` - `Structure`, справа от этого пункта меню будет текущее назначенное сочетание клавиш. А скорее всего - эта панель уже видна у вас, только в свернутом состоянии. Посмотрите левую серую панельку. На вашем скрине снизу на ней вкладка Favorites, сверху - PRoject и Structure

Comment: Cлева вертикальное меню - project и structure. Нажмите на structure

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Comment: ctrl + F12     ......

Answer (score 3):

View => Tool Windows => Structure

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

тоже искал. мало ли кому пригодится потом: CTRL+O

Answer (score 1):

Если нажать **ctrl + f12**, то можно увидеть все методы и переменные класса

[image: Можно увидеть все методы класса]